# Cairo: let vs tempvar what is the difference?

Tags: cairo-lang

I'm new to Cairo and I want to know what is the difference when I write `let x = 1;` and `tempvar x = 1;`. Is there any difference in Cairo Lang between let and tempvar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a difference. The keyword `let` creates a reference that's resolved by the compiler while `tempvar` actually stores the variable in the stack using a specialized register called the `ap` pointer. You can find more information about it [here](https://www.cairo-lang.org/docs/how_cairo_works/consts.html#references)